# Left front headlight on a 2023 crv does not turn on. Anyone knows the fuse location. Hondas manual does not show it

Tags: headlight, fuse, crv

Need location for the fuses that control the left front headlight on a 2023 Honda crv.

Comment: I have never known a headlamp fuse to blow, but have had plenty of bulbs go. But what do you mean by 'control'? Do you mean the headlamp level adjuster, which the driver can operate?

Comment: Look under the hood for a box in the vicinity of the battery that contains relays and/or circuit breakers. Open the box and there should be a legend.

Comment: Lots of options when Googling "2023 honda crv fuse box diagram"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community The question seems fairly clear to me.  The OP is asking for the location of the fuse for the front left headlight for a 2013 Honda CR-V.

Comment: If it is a 2023 Honda as stated, take it to the dealer.

Comment: Have you tried swapping bulbs side to side and confirmed that the problem *doesn't* follow the bulb?

Answer (score 1):

On page 683 of the [owners manual](https://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/AH/A3D42323OMEN/enu/A3D42323OMEN.PDF),it shows the location of the main fuse box -

[image]

On page 684 it shows the circuits protected by the fuses -

[image]

Fuse 27 (LCM L) will be the left light control module.

This is likely the fuse you need to check.

My guess, however, would be that there is a fault with the headlight or the control module.

As suggested in the comments above, this vehicle should still be under warranty, so best take it back to the dealer.